# Does Evernote limit the amount of notes you create based on their types?

Tags: evernote

When I go to the account settings, I see something like this:

> Approximate notes remaining:
>
> - Typed notes:    20,000
> - Web clips:  270
> - Camera phone:   400
> - Audio:  39
> - High res photos:    11

Are these limitations based on the average size of the type of note<sup>[1]</sup>, or are they actually limiting you based on the type of note you create?

In other words, if I'm only uploading tiny audio files (e.g. 10 KB), can I upload hundreds of them (as long as I don't go over my monthly MB limit)? Or am I actually restricted to 39 audio files no matter the size?

[1]: For example, they use a calculation such as: The average size of high res photo is 3.5MB. You have 40MB left, so 40MB / 3.5MB = about 11MB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It is based solely on filesize.**

You can upload whatever you want until you reach 40mb for the month, provided the individual files don't exceed 25mb.

Answer (score 0):

Evenote states on [their](http://www.evernote.com/about/premium/) page that:

- Free accounts can upload not more than 40mb / month
- Premium accounts can upload not more than 500mb / month

Additionally you can only create some filetypes in the free version.